# How to Handle jsonp errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm making a jsonp request with jquery.ajax() like this:

```
var cep = 99999999;
$.ajax({
    url: "http://cep.paicon.com.br/jsonp/"+ cep +"?callback=addressFunction",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: false
})
```

When there alright, the requested page call my callback function normally.

But, in some situations, the requested page don't return anything.

How can i handle this error, since it won't call any callback function?

Thanks!

(Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a timeout on your $.ajax() call, and handle the lack of response via that mechanism.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://cep.paicon.com.br/jsonp/"+ cep +"?callback=addressFunction",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  timeout: 2000,
  success: function(response) { alert(response); },
  error: function(x, t, m) {
      if(t==="timeout") {
          alert("got timeout");
      } else {
          alert(t);
      }
  }
});​
```

Comment: The problem is that an empty response from the server is a valid `<script>` element. Note that JSONP is not done with XMLHttpRequest and the timeout mechanism probably won't work in IE.

Comment: I interpreted his "doesn't return anything" as a timeout, not a blank response.

Comment: yes it may be that that's what he meant, but even so, browsers are not very reliable in providing feedback about dynamically added `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle that.  The server must be made to always return some JavaScript, which in the case of an error might be something that calls some pre-arranged error handler function, or whatever seems appropriate.

Comment: already suspected that.
if the server does not return anything. I can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

If your requested page returns nothing, then you need to wrap it in some code so it returns an error code in some JSON. So, you could decorate the request service with something that has a timeout and then returns some json that might be:

```
{
   errorCode: "requestTimeout"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got handle the error with the textStatus == "parsererror" in $.ajax error setting.

Now my function is like that:

```
function buscaEndereco(cep){
    url = "http://cep.paicon.com.br/jsonp/"+ cep;
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       crossDomain: true,
       timeout: 10000,
       success: function(response){ 
           montaEndereco(response); 
       },
       error: function(x, t, m){
           if(t == "timeout"){
           alert("Timeout");
           } else {
            if(t == "parsererror"){
               alert("CEP not found");
            } else {
               alert(t);
            }
           }
       }
    });
}
```

Thanks